# Oauth2 obtaining token with grant_type client_credentials

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to obtain a token for oauth2 authentication to connect to a mail server using the following Java code:

```
public static String getAuthToken(String tenantId, String clientId, String client_secret) throws ClientProtocolException , IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    //String scopes = "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All";
    String scopes = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"; // we need this scope when we have the grand_type as client credidentials

    //String encodedBody = "client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=" + scopes + "&client_secret=" + client_secret+ "&username="+mailAddress+"&password=" + EMAIL_PASSWORD + "&grant_type=password";
    String encodedBody = "client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=" + scopes + "&client_secret=" + client_secret+ "&username="+mailAddress+ "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    loginPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(encodedBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
    loginPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"));
    CloseableHttpResponse loginResponse = client.execute(loginPost);
    InputStream inputStream = loginResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    byte[] response = readAllBytes(inputStream);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = objectMapper.constructType(
        objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Map.class, String.class, String.class));
    Map<String, String> parsed = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, type);
    return parsed.get("access_token");
}
```

Yet if I try to get the token without having the password in the request body (if I add the password like in the commented line, all works fine), I cannot connect with that token and get the following authentication failed error:

`Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed. at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) at yk.Auth.main(Auth.java:79)`

I've tried adapting the request body (changing/removing the scope etc.) but nothing changes.
What needs to be done in order to obtain a valid token without sending the password as part of the request?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know specifics of the Azure API, but the [client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2) is supposed to create a token for an OAuth2 client, not a user - it's for a service-to-service communication. If you need a token authorized by a user, you probably need to request it from them and use the auth code grant.

Comment: figure this out on Postman before writing code. There's probably an issue (or a misunderstanding)  with the client registration. Reach out to the people who manage the identity server and work it out with them.

Comment: @JánHalaša i have also tried it to run  without username but i am still having the same authentication error.

Comment: @DerekGusoff thank you for your answer , I cannot figure it out on Postman because I do get an authentication token even without the password, it just is not a valid token. Would you see what kind of issue could that be ?

Comment: @YuliyaKalcheva You probably need a token authorized by a user to access the IMAP server. Because your OAuth2 client (identified by clientId) is not the IMAP server user. The line you commented out uses the password grant (which is deprecated) and requires the user's password. The token you get using the client_credentials grant is probably not usable for the IMAP server. Could it be so?

Comment: thanks @JánHalaša.  That might be a reason. Do you know how can i authorize it to access IMAP server. I am very lost. The only way to make it work is specifiying the password and using password grants.

Comment: @YuliyaKalcheva OK, I will write a full answer.

Comment: @YuliyaKalcheva Was the answer helpful? If you solved the problem in some other way, it's good to write it here for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic answer that could be improved by someone with better knowledge of MS Azure services.

You probably need a token authorized by a user to access the IMAP server. Because your OAuth2 client (identified by clientId) is not the IMAP server user - the token you get using the client_credentials grant is not usable for the IMAP server. The line you commented out uses the password grant (which is [deprecated](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/)) and requires the user's password.

I think the correct way from the OAuth2 standpoint is to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). This way, the user (resource owner role) delegates their rights (represented by the requested scopes) to your application (OAuth2 client role) which can use them at the IMAP server (resource server role).

The auth code flow requires user interaction - the user's browser gets redirected to the OAuth2 auth endpoint, the user gets authenticated and gives consent with delegating the requested rights to your application. Then your the browser is redirect to the `redirect_uri` handled by your application. The request has an auth code value which can be exchanged for tokens at the token endpoint of the OAuth2 server.

If your application doesn't interact with users who could delegate their IMAP server access, you probably need to use the password grant or figure out how to make your application (identified by its `client_id`) an IMAP user and use the client_credentials grant (as you do now).